# How do I unbind or prevent other click events from occurring while my function is running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a carousel set up and I have click events tied to the navigation arrows. When they are clicked I use jQuery animate to animate in the elements of the next carousel slide, and due to the nature of the animations I use `setTimeout()` a few times.

I have one bug, where if I click on an arrow, and then quickly click the previous or next arrow, the animation will get confused due to the timeouts (which are necessary in this project) and render nothing on the screen. I've looked at this for awhile, and I figure that the best method might be to prevent the other arrows from being clickable until the current animation has completed.

Each arrow is controlled by `click` not `on:('click', function() ...` etc:

```
$("#arrow1").click(function() {...}
```

I've looked at

```
$("element").off("click");
```

But as they are not attached using the 'on' method I don't think this will work.

I want something like:

```
$("#arrow1").click(function() {
 $("#arrow2, #arrow3, #arrow4").off("click");
 // do my animations, then
 $("#arrow2, #arrow3, #arrow4").on("click");
}
```

But I haven't been able to get this to work yet.

Comment: Sounds like you want to throttle your event handling function https://lodash.com/docs#throttle

Answer (score 5):

`.off` and `.on` do not work as you expect. The `.click` method and other event methods use the `.on` method behind the scenes for binding the handlers. When the `.off` method is called without any specific handlers it *removes* (and not temporary disables) all the bound handlers for a specific event. And calling `.on` without passing a handler has no effect.

In your case you can use a flag instead of manipulating event handlers which is also more efficient than (re)binding and removing the event handlers.

Comment: The flag may be the best option. You hould check the flag in the function called by the listener. If the flag is "true" or 1, just return without making anything. Then, you set the flag as true when you need to disable onclick function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the unbind function

```
$("#arrow1").click(function() {
 // $("#arrow2, #arrow3, #arrow4").off("click");
 $("#arrow2, #arrow3, #arrow4").unbind("click");
 // do my animations, then
 $("#arrow2, #arrow3, #arrow4").on("click");
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)**  function it should remove the event.

> **Description:** Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.

```
$("#arrow1").unbind( "click" );
```

The **[`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** function should work also.

> **Description:** Remove an event handler.

```
$("#arrow1").off( "click" );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is set a boolean isLoading = false from the beginning. Then while the function is executing set:

isLoading = true. If isLoading == true, $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); else enable it

When it completes then change it back to false.

Sorry it's psudo code, it's just off the top of my head.